# Print data from a text file imported into a hash map, ignore characters

Tags: java, eclipse, import, hashmap

I have a text file that contains the following:

example.txt

```
#ignore
#ignore line
#ignore line again
1234567
8940116
12131415
```

I want to read in the example.txt file into eclipse and add the data into a hashmap. I want the list to be arranged in numerical order and I want it to ignore any comments(any text with #) in the text file. I would like to print the hashmap as follows:

output:

```
1234567
8940116
12131415
```

Comment: Your sentences all begin with "I want...", but it is not obvious that you have tried anything at all to achieve what you want. You can find here, but also elsewhere online how to read a file, how to skip certain lines, how to check if a string starts with a certain character.... Try it yourself first. If you can't get any further show where you are stuck. Apart from that, a map is a container for data pairs which act as key and value. Your example data doesn't look like they represent such pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a hashmap for storing just Strings. Maps are for key value pairs. If you want to put each line from file into a collection use Lists. ArrayLists, LinkedList maintain insertion order. You can use any of them. If you want sorted list you can use TreeList.

```
    BufferedReader reader;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "example"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if(!line.startsWith("#"){
                list.add(line);
              }
              line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I prefer the hashmap. The output is in the format of [, , ,]. I added a print statement

Answer (score 0):

Thr purpose of a `Map` is to store pairs `Key/Value`, for a single collection you may use a `List` it's far more efficient, the printing part is you job whatever the type of collection is

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
            values.add(line);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for (String v : values)
    System.out.println(v);
```